# Qualtrics - progress to next block when time is up

Tags: javascript, timer, qualtrics

I need a survey to auto progress to the next block when a specified time limit has been reached for the previous block. Currently I am using the below script to display the timer but need the script to execute the action when time has elapsed. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Javascript in timing question.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    var headerCont = document.createElement("div");  
 headerCont.className = "header-cont";  
 headerCont.id = "header_container";  
 var header = document.createElement("div");  
 header.className = "header"  
 header.id = "header_1";  
 var timer = document.createElement("div");  
 timer.className = "timer";  
 timer.id = "timer_1";  
 timer.innerHTML = "Time Remaining: <span id='time'>00:10</span>";  
 headerCont.appendChild(header);  
 header.appendChild(timer);  
 document.body.insertBefore(headerCont, document.body.firstChild);
function startTimer(duration, display) {  
  var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;  
  var myTimer = setInterval(function() {  
   minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)  
   seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);  
   minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;  
   seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;  
   var text = ('innerText' in display)? 'innerText' : 'textContent';
   display[text] = minutes + ":" + seconds;  
   if (--timer < 0) {  
    clearInterval(myTimer);  
    timeOver();  
   }  
  }, 1000);  
 }  
 var timerSeconds = 10,  
 display = document.querySelector('#time');  
 startTimer(timerSeconds, display);  
 var timeOver = function() {  
     document.getElementById("timer_1").innerHTML = "Time is up.";}



});
```

CSS

```
    .header-cont {  
   width:100%;  
   position:fixed;  
   top:0px;  
   z-index:1000;  
 }  
 .header {  
   height:75px;  
   background:#FFFFFF;  
   width:100%;  
   margin:0px auto;  
 }  
 .timer{   
   margin: auto;  
   text-align: center;  
   vertical-align: middle;        
   font-size: 200%;
    font-family: Arial;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED ANSWER BASED ON COMMENT:

Initialize an embedded data field in the survey flow before block:

```
blockTimeFlag = 0
```

Add the following lines to the timeOver function:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("blockTimeFlag", "1");    
$('NextButton').click();
```

However, this means that none of your questions can be forced response.

Add display logic to your questions:

```
if blockTimeFlag = 0
```

Comment: Thanks - that works to progress to next question, however I am wanting the survey to move to next block when time is over not just the next page (unless they are on the last question in the block).

Comment: Thanks that works. I have also got a bit a of workaround for forced choice via hiding next button until answer selected. Now I wish repeat the process for the next block and restart the timer. Currently the timer continues to appear on the next block. Any advice?

Comment: It appears your script resets the count to 10 secs on every page. If that is what you want, all you have to do reset blockTimeFlag to zero before the next block. If you are really meaning to keep a running time for the block, this post may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36948956/implementing-a-multi-page-timer-in-qualtrics/36956653#36956653